# C++ std::string::at()

Tags: c++, string

I want to print the first letter of a string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str = "다람쥐 헌 쳇바퀴 돌고파.";
  cout << str.at(0) << endl;
}
```

I want `'다'` to be printed like java, but `'?'` is printed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you know about character encodings?

Comment: use locale with your current set of characters

Comment: @Gabriel Won't help. I am not aware of a character encoding where 다 would be representable by a single (8-bit) `char` value.

Comment: Use a u16string instead, thats what java is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text you have in `str` -- how is it encoded?

Unfortunately, you need to know that to get the first "character". The std::string class only deals with bytes. How bytes turn into characters is a rather large topic.

The magic word you are probably looking for is UTF-8. See here for more infomation: [How do I properly use std::string on UTF-8 in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403342/how-do-i-properly-use-stdstring-on-utf-8-in-c)

If you want to go down this road yourself, look here: [Extract (first) UTF-8 character from a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774630/extract-first-utf-8-character-from-a-stdstring)

And if you're really interested, here's an hour-long video that is actually a great explanation of text encoding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mZBa3sqTrI