# Reading from files and comparing/ merging data to create a new file

Tags: c++

I would really like some help in figuring this out. 
I have two files, one txt file and one xls file, in the txt file it contains a list of student names and their ID. In the xls file it contains alphabet letters and some numbers assigned to them. 
I need to create a new txt file for every student, with their ID as filename. And in this file, I need to show the numbers that are assigned to the alphabet which makes up the student's name. Please help me, really cant figure it out within the time given [txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWvD5.jpg)[xls file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SosTt.jpg)[image: Alphabet.txt]

What I've been able to do so far using C++ is to read the data from the txt file and i convert the xls file into a txt file as well and read from that as well. Do i need to store the data in an array or its easier to just convert to the resulting file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream inputa("Students.txt");
    ifstream inputb("Alphabet.txt");
    if (!inputb.is_open()) std::cout << "Error: File Not Open" << '\n';


/* ofstream output;
output.open("output.txt");
 This was just to see if it was getting anything 
*/

string name;
string id;
string alphabet;
string number;


while (inputa >> name >> id || inputb >> alphabet >> number) { 
    /* here i planned to compare the strings using string::find, but it doesnt work */

    }







system("pause");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: If you expect a quality answer, you will need to provide a simple example and some code that isn't working. Since you have already figured out how to convert the xls file, please give an inline example of the two files, the expected output file, and your code that doesn't work or is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I added  it now

Comment: You should also include the converted xls file that you actually load ("Alphabet.txt"). It is impossible to give you the precise answer without the actual inputs.
On a glance it looks like you should first read the whole alphabet with the assigned numbers into some kind of collection (map possibly?)

Comment: Thanks Kirsz for the reply, i also added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, you still haven't given an example of what the file that holds IDs and student names looks like, so I might have gotten the ordering wrong, but you should get the idea.

I would just read the alphabet file in, storing the encoding, followed by writing out all of the student files in one step:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

static int encoding_map[256] = {0};

bool load_encoding(const char* file_name)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(file_name);
    if (!file.is_open()) return false;

    char from = 0;
    int to = 0;
    while (file >> from >> to) encoding_map[(int)from] = to;

    return true;
}

bool write_student_files(const char* src_file)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(src_file);
    if (!file.is_open()) return false;

    std::string id;
    std::string name;

    std::ofstream outfile;
    while (file >> id >> name)
    {
        outfile.open(id + ".txt");
        for (char c : name) outfile << encoding_map[(int)c];
        outfile << '\n';
        outfile.close();
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    load_encoding("encoding.txt");
    write_student_files("students.txt");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my encoding file (alphabet file), `encoding.txt`:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
i 9
j 10
k 11
l 12
m 13
n 14
o 15
p 16
q 17
r 18
s 19
t 20
u 21
v 22
w 23
x 24
y 25
z 26
```

and here is my students file, `students.txt`:

```
0 bob
1 susan
2 joe
3 becky
```

If I compile the code with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` and run it, I get 4 new files in the same directory:

```
0.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

The contents of `0.txt`, for example, is:

```
2152
```

You can mess with the spaces if you want, but, with my simple encoding:

```
b => 2
o => 15
b => 2
```

meaning the output is correct(though not very pretty).

Clearly, this does not do much error handling, doesn't handle names with multiple words, etc., but you should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Thank you rationalcoder, this was very clear and helpful in the way of me learning more about c++.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing, What if in the student file, the names of the students were changed to random strings and symbols or phonics like omega, and in the encoding file the alphabets were all changed to individual symbols and a string as well, would this method work too?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to use utf-8 capable encoding. This is ascii specific. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Im still novice at c++, would you mind explaining to me how do I use or switch to utf-8 capable encoding?

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you but if its possible could you check out my new question regarding this, its here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549101/how-to-maniplulate-unicode-utf-8-file-data-in-c/44557798#44557798)

Comment: I retract my earlier comment about switching to wchar_t. I've never actually needed utf-8 support, so I was wrong. Apparently, wchar_t is a kind of a hack. In this case, if you want to support Unicode characters, you would need to parse the characters into a uint32_t and map those to other integers. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948308/how-do-i-read-utf-8-characters-via-a-pointer/2953960#2953960 It is admittedly complicated.

Comment: That being said, by googling around, I have found many easy (but probably non portable) ways to do this. I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I would probably get fired if i don't solve this by tomorrow

Comment: There's char16_t but isnt supported in iostream

Comment: Alright, I have been looking around, and even I am getting confused. Sorry, but it doesn't look like I am going to be able to help you.

Comment: I represented utf8 into hex, but....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580296/cross-referencing-data-from-file

Comment: You have just made a harder problem for yourself. I can solve that one, but know that your solution will be unnecessarily slow.

Comment: How do you add a reference to a map? Also thank you for helping me so much already when you could've ignored me

Comment: Is it possible you answer the question there?

Comment: I did something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712292/stringfind-and-iterate-through-to-write-in-an-order?noredirect=1#comment76418742_44712292) But stuck on something small but important