# How to read UTF-8 file data in C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, io

I have a list of [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (UTF-8) symbols in a text file called ipa.txt with numbers assigned to them. How do I cross reference it with a source file which is also a text file that contains a bunch of words and their corresponding IPA, to return a text file for every names with their names as their filename and inside the text file should contain their corresponding numbers of IPA.

Below is what I've tried but didn't work, only outputs were mostly 000000.

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map <wchar_t, int> map;
    std::wifstream file;
    file.open("ipa.txt");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "opened ipa file";
    }

    wchar_t from;
    int to;
    while (file >> from >> to) {
        map.insert(std::make_pair(from, to));
    }

    std::wifstream outfile;
    outfile.open("source.txt");
    if (outfile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "opened source file";
    }

    std::wstring id;
    std::wstring name;
    while (outfile >> id >> name) {
        std::ofstream outputfile;
        outputfile.open(id + L".txt");
        for (wchar_t c : name)  outputfile << map[c]; 
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer, hellishly. But please, don't paste pictures, paste the actual text.

Comment: Thanks, done that

Comment: Did you trace through your code in a debugger?  I did, in Visual Studio 2017. Both of your input files have a BOM which causes the first read to fail, and even with the BOM removed only the first pair of items is read from the file. The second read grabs the first byte of the utf-8 character and then fails because the next byte isn't a number. 0x5453 is on the right track with using narrow strings, but that doesn't work with your last step since you need to isolate each utf-8 character. Short answer, use a utf-8 library for this.  https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp is simple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the wrong type for `c` used in the iteration over `name`. As `c` is used as key for the map, and `name` is a `wstring`, you should use:

```
for (wchar_t c : name)  outputfile << map[c];
```

instead of:

```
for (char c : name)  outputfile << map[c];
```

Isn't it?

Hope this may help, Stefano

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but it still returns 000000s in the resulting files generated

Answer (score 0):

First thought:

```
map <- std::unordered_map<char, int>
open ipa.txt:
    for each line in file:
        map[line[0]] = line[1]
open source.txt:
    for each line in file:
        create and open line[0].txt:
            for each char in line[1]:
                write map[char] to line[0].txt
```

Regarding the actual C++ implementation, AFAIK utf-8 should fit inside `char` and `std::string` so you don't have to do anything special there.  If you need utf-8 string literals you must use the `u8` prefix: `u8"literal"`.  Everything else should be standard file IO.

EDIT: Here are some links to the relevant documentation to help you get started:

- [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) (for reading from files)
- [ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) (for writing to files)
- [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (for mapping 'keys' to 'values')

Outside of that it will probably just take a little Googling.  File IO is very common so I'm sure you can find some good examples online.  As long as your file format is consistent you shouldn't have too much trouble with the file parsing.  Then the rest of it is just storing values in the map and then looking them up when you need them, which is pretty simple.

Comment: I'm kind of new to C++ , if you could elaborate further that would be extremely helpful, thank you

Comment: Someone told me if I just added all the ipa symbols as variables it would be easier, is he right or is he just messing with me?

Comment: utf8 doesnt fit in char or wchar_t, it does with char16_t but it doesnt support iostream