# Cross referencing data from file

Tags: c++

Cant figure this out....I got two txt files, one is encoding1.txt which contains a set of hexadecimals and the ID number that is assigned to them, such as

```
61           1
C3A4         2      
C990         4
C991         5
C991CC83     6
C992         7
CA8C         9
```

The other file source.txt is the source file which contains a bunch of combined hex and the students' names

```
CA8CC992    Jack
C991C3A4    Amy
C991CC83    Sam
61C991      Tom
```

I want to output a txt file for each students with their name as their filenames and inside the file should be the assigned numbers of their hex. e.g. for jack.txt, inside it should be

```
9
7
```

Below is the code that I've tried it generates all the test file  but inside its jack.txt theres only  9 and other files are empty. Whats the correct way to do this and how do I get the results right?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include<map>
//#include<unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include<array>
//#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
   int main()
{
std::ifstream file;
file.open("encoding1.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "opened encoding1 file";
}
std::ifstream file2;
file2.open("source.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "opened source file" << std::endl;
}
std::ofstream outfile;
const int hexencosize = 7;
std::string hexenco[hexencosize] = {};
int id[7] = {};
std::string hexsource;
string * p;
std::string name;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    while (file >> hexenco[i] >> id[i]) {
        std::cout << "hexenco is " << hexenco[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "id is " << id[i] << std::endl;
    };
for (int o = 0; o < 6; o++) 
while (file2 >> hexsource >> name) {

    outfile.open(name + ".txt");

             std::size_t found = hexsource.find(hexenco[o]);
             if (found != std::string::npos) 


            p = std::find(hexenco, hexenco + hexencosize, hexenco[o]);

            if (p >= hexenco + hexencosize) std::cout << "Not found" << 
std::endl;
            else outfile << id[p - hexenco] << '\n';


            outfile.close();

};


system("pause");
return 0;
};
```

Comment: You need `outfile.close()` to go with `outfile.open`. As written, the second `open` in a row simply fails.

Comment: `for (it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++);` This loop does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, the file names are generating fine now, but there's only 9 in jack.txt  and otheres are emtpy

Comment: You have apparently addressed one of the problems I identified, but not the other.

Comment: I know, Just that I dont know how to make use of it to loop through

Comment: or how to use maps correctly

Comment: you can use substr function to check if hexcode in encoding1.txt is a substring or not of source.txt hexcode and if it is append 'id' in name.txt file. Use try and catch to handle exception if using substr an example -> http://ideone.com/nCIGsg