# String::find and iterate through to write in an order

Tags: c++, loops

I made three arrays, hexsource[ ], hexenco[ ], and ip[ ]. I used string::find to check if hexenco[ ] contains hexsource[ ], if true then write ip[ ] into a file.
Code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <113; i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o <10; o++) {

            size_t found = hexsource[o].find(hexenco[i]);
            if (found != std::string::npos) {


                std::ofstream outfile("Output_files\\" + name[o] + ".txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);

                outfile << "Sound Bite No: "  << ip[i] << std::endl;

                outfile.close();
            }
            found = hexsource[o].find(hexenco[i], found + 1);
            if (found != std::string::npos) {

                std::ofstream outfile("Output_files\\" + name[o] + ".txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
                outfile << "Sound Bite No: " << ip[i] << std::endl;

                outfile.close();
            } } }
```

How do I output ip[] in such a way that its in an order of hexsource[ ]?

For example, if hexsource[4] = {"C9916674C9996E756E"}; which is **ɑːftəˈnuːn** in hex form, hexenco[ ] contains a bunch of utf-8 characters in their hex numbers, and ip[ ] contains numbers assigned to the utf-8 characters.
When I run my code it generated

```
No: 4          // which is assigned to ɑ
No: 42         // which is assigned to ə
No: 51         // which is assigned to f
No:131         // which is assigned to n
No: 131        // which is assigned to n
No:191         // which is assigned to t
No:201         // which is assigned to u
```

The order that I want is

```
No: 4          // which is assigned to ɑ
No: 51         // which is assigned to f
No:191         // which is assigned to t
No: 42         // which is assigned to ə
No:131         // which is assigned to n
No:201         // which is assigned to u
No:131         // which is assigned to n
```

I tried implementing iterate through string method but didnt work

```
for (unsigned p = 0; p < 10; ++p) {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < hexsource[p].size(); ++j) {
                    ss << hexsource[p][j];}
```

Test for unicode characters instead of their hex number that always generated an extra No. 62:

```
int main()
{
std::wofstream pfile;
pfile.open(L"myfile.txt");

std::wifstream ufile(L"List.txt");


std::wifstream filere(L"hexhexsource.txt");
std::wstring line[302];
std::wstring ipasymbol[113];
std::wstring hexl[113];
std::wstring ipano[113];
std::wstring st[113];
std::wstring end[113];

for (int i = 0; i < 113; ++i) ufile >> ipasymbol[i] >> hexl[i] >> ipano[i] >> st[i] >> end[i];

for (int o = 0; o < 302; ++o) {
    while (getline(filere, line[o]))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 113; ++i)
        {

            size_t found =  line[o] .find(ipasymbol[i]);
            if (found != std::wstring::npos ) {
                wcout<< line[o] << L"is equal to" << ipano[i]<<endl;
                pfile << line[o] << "is equal to" << ipano[i];
                pfile << "\n";}
            }pfile.close();

        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the types of your objects, I can only make some guesses.  You're testing each element of `hexenco` from 0 to 113 against `hexsource`. Instead, I think you should be testing each unicode character in `hexsource` against the `hexenco` list.

Comment: I also tried that but that method always generated an extra no.62

Comment: That does not mean that method is plain wrong, it might just be buggy.  In my opinion, the algorithm used in the question is less likely to be closer to the correct algorithm than your buggy method.

Comment: Even in that case, how should I get the right order of the No.

Comment: Do you think I should use a vector instead, will it make much of a difference?

Comment: And what be the `ipasymbol[i]` when `ipano[i]` is 62?

Comment: I suggest you figure out why 62 is so special. I don't see why changing to a vector will help, unless you are aware of some limitation of raw arrays that is relevant to this problem.